# AsyncTask.execute() and change UI

Tags: java, android

In my case, I use AsyncTask.execute() method to connect to the Room database and change UI elements:

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
  Database db = Room.databaseBuilder(this.getApplicationContext(),
          Database.class, "name-database").build();
  Dao dao = db.getDao();
  if (dao.findByNumber(1).isOpen) { // get data from the database
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_button_shape) // change UI-element
  }
});
```

Is this a thread-safe solution?, or need to create a separate class with an overridden onPostExecute() method for change UI? Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

On the advice of Priyankagb I began to use runOnUiThread():

```
if (dao.findByNumber(1).isOpen) { 
  runOnUiThread(() -> button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_button_shape)); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not thread-safe. You have to use `onPostExecute()` or also you can use `runOnUiThread()` to change a button background into direct `execute()`

like...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_button_shape) 
     }
});
```